# Tengo que devolver un objeto con la propiedad nombre (del vehículo) y su valor es la cantidad de veces que se repite en el array

Tags: javascript, array, bucle-for, objeto

Tengo la siguiente función, la cual recibe un array de strings como argumento que contiene tipos de vehículos y debe devolver un objeto con la cantidad de veces que se repita cada tipo.

El objeto que devuelve tiene como propiedades el nombre de cada vehículo y su valor es la cantidad de veces que se repite.

Ejemplo:

```javascript
sumarElTipo(['auto', 'moto', 'auto']); //debe retornar {auto: 2, moto: 1}
```

Creo un objeto vacío, luego aplico un bucle for y con un condicional para ver si los elementos se repiten, en caso de ser así hago un push sobre el objeto vacío y luego un return (sé que mi código está mal).

```javascript
function sumarElTipo(arreglo) {
   var objeto = {};
   for(var i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++){
       arreglo[i] === arreglo[i+1]{
         objeto.push(arreglo[i], arreglo.length);
       }
   }
   return objeto;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solución

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```js
function sumarElTipo(arr) {
  times = {}; // Creamos un objeto vacio
  arr.forEach(item => {
    if (times[item]) {
      times[item]+=1; // si el item está en el objeto, le sumamos 1
    } else {
      times[item]=1; // Si no, le asignamos el valor 1
    }
  });
  return times; // devolvemos el objeto
}

console.log(sumarElTipo(['auto', 'moto', 'auto'])); // retorna {auto: 2, moto: 1}
console.log(sumarElTipo(['auto','auto', 'moto', 'auto'])); // retorna {auto: 3, moto: 1}
```

### Explicación

Lo que hacemos es recorrer el arreglo con la funcion [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), la cual ejecuta una función por cada elemento del arreglo.

Luego preguntamos para cada item, si existe como clave en el objeto `times` (podría llamarse de cualquier otra forma). Si existe, aumentamos la cuenta, si no existe, le asignamos el valor `1`.

¿Cómo funciona eso de `times[item]`?

Esta expresión se llama [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#bracket_notation) y te permite acceder a las propiedades de un objeto usando una variable (en este caso una cadena).

Veamos un ejemplo de qué devuelve esta expresión si no existe la propiedad en el objeto:

```js
times = {
  "propiedad1": "hola"
};

console.log(times["propiedad1"]); // devuelve la cadena "hola"
console.log(times["propiedadQueNoExiste"]); // devuelve undefined

console.log(times);

// ahora asignemos esa propiedad al objeto

times["propiedadQueNoExiste"] = 1;

console.log(times["propiedadQueNoExiste"]); // devuelve 1 ya que lo acabamos de asignar
console.log(times);
```

Comment: Perfecto me sirvió, gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Usando `.reduce` podemos también ir guardando el objeto en el acumulador y con `in` verificamos si está o no. Si está sumamos 1, sino le asignamos 1;

```js
const sumarTipo = (ar) => ar.reduce((p, c) => (((c in p) ? p[c] += 1: p[c] = 1) && p),{});

console.log(sumarTipo(['auto', 'moto', 'auto']));
```